# Facebook login/registration: Error validating verification code

Tags: django, facebook-graph-api, oauth, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am using [django-rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth) which uses [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) for social logins. I set login for facebook according the rest-auth documentation. This is a view. Authentication works, but the email for the user was empty. So I add **callback_url** and **client_class** (like documentation said).

```
from rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.oauth2.client import OAuth2Client


class FacebookLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = FacebookOAuth2Adapter
    callback_url = 'http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/facebook/'
    client_class = OAuth2Client
```

But it is not working. It returns this error:

> Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request

First I think the problem is in the library. So I printed out all parameters for the request and I check all these things. Everything looks fine, so I tried to put the URL with these parameters to [Facebook Graph API](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/oauth/access_token). But the error is the same. Here is the all URL which I tried manually, without using the allauth library:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/oauth/access_token?redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/facebook/&client_id=203192345223034931&client_secret=a475bbbscds65437c89bf04d359d98a&code=203192345223034931|l3ujbbbscdhrf0404d3B2de57Dw
```

**cliend_id** and **client_secret** I took from Facebook developers console from Dashboard. And the **code** is App Token from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/)

In the facebook developers interface I set:

**Valid OAuth redirect URIs:** http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/facebook/

**App domains:** localhost

Because I tried it manually in my browser I hope it won't be a problem with libraries but with my settings or my misunderstanding of something.

I tried it with the normal domain, but it has not come any change.

Comment: _“And the code is App Token from here”_ - that’s wrong. The `code` parameter is no fixed value, but a random one you get back from the login dialog redirect.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I still don't understand it. I can get User access token via Facebook Javascript SDK on the client. Then I send User access token to my API. But how can I get the Code, via Facebook SDK as well?

Comment: You can’t, because there is no code parameter involved in the client-side login flow to begin with. The only purpose of the code, is to be exchanged for a short-lived user access token. You already have a token, so why you would want to do the same thing again on the server-side is unclear.

Comment: Because I don't understand what should be managed on the client and what on the server. So what I want to do with User Access token: 1. Users clicked on the Facebook login button, 2. Via Facebook Javascript SDK is opened the pop up with permission info (permission for using email of user for example), 3. In this time client gains User Access Token which is then send to my API. If user already have accept the permissions then it will be only User Access token was gained. Is this good and standard approach how to login user? If yes, so how looks process using the code?

Comment: You send the token to the server, and use it to make API calls from there. You do not query any user data on the client and send it to the server - that would be easy to fake. So token only, and then you request user id, name, etc. using that.

Comment: The server-side/redirect login flow, that uses the `code` parameter, is described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

Comment: Yes, I understand that client sends only User access token. Using User token access I can get user info when registration/login is called on API. But first I need to get permission from a user. This is done on the client together with getting User Access token. Is this right?.Thank you for the link. If I understand it well, it means that I can call from the client request on Facebook login api which returns code on redirected_uri (this will be my API endpoint which takes code). This the second way.